# The position of one word is changing from one slide to another

Tags: beamer, positioning

I am using the `beamer` class.

Here, I want the position of "BC" in the second and third slides to be the same. However, this is not the case. Why is that? How should I fix that?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
     \only<1,3->{A}
     \only<2>{\textcolor{blue}{A}}
     \only<2>{BC}
   \only<3->{\textcolor{blue}{BC}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After commenting out two end-of-line characters (on the line where the first possible styles of `A`/`BC` is given):

```tex
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
    \only<1,3->{A}%
    \only<2>{\textcolor{blue}{A}}
    \only<2>{BC}%
    \only<3->{\textcolor{blue}{BC}}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<3->Item
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Before
[image]

After
[image]